# Disable Windows Phone in Phonegap Build

Tags: phonegap-build

Is it possible to disable builds for Windows Phone in [Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/)?

Let me know if it's possible, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Renesansz,
This item is poorly documented, but you need to add a line to your config.xml.
Here is your documentation:
[The Basics](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_basics.md.html)

Here is a working example:
[Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap--Generic-Boilerplate)

The Blog on the boilerplate is here:
[Three (3) Phonegap Build Boilerplates for For Android and iOS](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/2015/BLOG.2015-06-19.codesnippets.html)

You will want to read the **bold points** in this FAQ
[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Best of Luck,
Jesse

Comment: thanks! yeah, the docs is so confusing that you really need to dig deeper.