# Phonegap build only shows iOS and Android, no windows

Tags: windows, phonegap-build

After upload to Phonegap Build, I only get options to build for iOs and for Android, but not for Windows phone.

With other apps I always got the three options. I have no idea why this is now different.

What do I need to do to also get the Windows Phone build option?

This is my config.xml file, maybe something is missing there?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "MyAppId"
    version   = "3.0.1">


<name>MyApName</name>
<description>MyAppDescription</description>

<author href="http://MyAppURL" email="MyAppMail@MyAppDomain.example">MyAppAuthor</author>

<preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>

<preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        
<preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      
<preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           
<preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           
<preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           
<preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="white-opaque" />   
<preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           
<preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="false" />          
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           
<preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          
<preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" />
<icon platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
<icon platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
<icon platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
<icon platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
<icon platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
<icon platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
<icon platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
<icon platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
<icon platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
<icon platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
<icon platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
<icon platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
<icon platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
<icon platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
<icon platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" height="152" />

<splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" height="480" />
<splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
<splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" height="1136" />
<splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750" height="1334" />
<splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208" />
<splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" height="1024" />
<splash platform="ios" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" height="2048" />

<icon platform="android" qualifier="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"/>
<icon platform="android" qualifier="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"/>
<icon platform="android" qualifier="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"/>
<icon platform="android" qualifier="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"/>
<icon platform="android" qualifier="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-144-xxhdpi.png"/>
<icon platform="android" qualifier="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-192-xxxhdpi.png"/>

<splash platform="android" qualifier="ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
<splash platform="android" qualifier="mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
<splash platform="android" qualifier="hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
<splash platform="android" qualifier="xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />

<icon platform="wp8" src="res/icons/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" height="99" />
<icon platform="wp8" src="res/icons/wp8/Background.png" width="159" height="159" />

<icon platform="windows" src="res/icons/windows8/logo.png" width="150" height="150" />
<icon platform="windows" src="res/icons/windows8/smalllogo.png" width="30" height="30" />
<icon platform="windows" src="res/icons/windows8/storelogo.png" width="50" height="50" />


<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
<string>3.0.1</string>
</gap:config-file>


<access origin="*"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems I was too quick asking...
I found this thread: [Disable Windows Phone in Phonegap Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32321865/disable-windows-phone-in-phonegap-build?rq=1)

And reading through the links in that thread I discovered that adding

```
 <platform name="android" />
 <platform name="ios" />
 <platform name="winphone" />
```

does the trick and allowes to also build for Windows Phone.